# React and typescript, Binding element 'todos' implicitly has an 'any' type." while passing props to child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

typescript complains the prop `{ todos }`, it says "Binding element 'todos' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Anyone could help me? I tried so many way still couldn't solve it..
Do I need to also pass the interface to the child?

```
//TodoList.tsx
import React from "react";

export default function TodoList({ todos }) {
  return <div>{todos.id}</div>;
}
```

```
//App.tsx
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { uuid } from "uuidv4";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

export default function App() {
  interface Todo {
    id: string;
    title: string | undefined;
    completed: boolean;
  }

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
  const refTitle = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const title = refTitle.current?.value;
    setTodos((todos) => {
      return [...todos, { id: uuid(), title: title, completed: false }];
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
      <input ref={refTitle} type="text" />
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `todos` as `props` of the `Todo` type array.

App.tsx

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";
import { Todo } from "./types";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
  const refTitle = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const title = refTitle.current?.value;
    setTodos((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      { id: uuid(), title: title, completed: false }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
      <input ref={refTitle} type="text" />
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

TodoList.tsx

```
import { Todo } from "./types";

export default function TodoList({ todos }: { todos: Todo[] }) {
  return (
    <>
      {todos.map((todo, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{todo.title}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

types.ts

```
export interface Todo {
  id: string;
  title: string | undefined;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

This is a result of React components only taking `objects` as arguments

Here's the working solution https://codesandbox.io/s/props-to-child-tsx-vuzo2s

Comment: I have created another sandbox with the `TodosList` interface added, and used it to pass the `todos` to the child component. https://codesandbox.io/s/props-to-child-tsx-forked-zskngf?file=/src/types.ts Hope it helps!

Comment: `import uuid from "react-uuid";` You'd better use `react-uuid` as uuidv4 is deprecated

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. So my issue was not only type, also I didn't map the todos array in TodoList.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the type of prop that you are passing onto the Todolist. Just
add your interface from app.tsx to todolist.tsx and there pass the type Todo to props.I have edited the same in the code snippets below.

```js
import React from "react";
import {Todo} from "./App"

export default function TodoList({ todos : Todo }) {
  return <div>{todos.id}</div>;
}
```

```js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { uuid } from "uuidv4";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

export interface Todo {
    id: string;
    title: string | undefined;
    completed: boolean;
  }


export default function App() {
  
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);
  const refTitle = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const title = refTitle.current?.value;
    setTodos((todos) => {
      return [...todos, { id: uuid(), title: title, completed: false }];
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos} />
      <input ref={refTitle} type="text" />
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}
```